# NPM mustache-render create multiple HTMLs with single template and multiple JSONs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs, mustache

I am using npm grunt-mustache-render (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mustache-render) to generate HTML files. I can create the html using 1 json and 1 template. Now, what I am trying is to create multiple HTML files based on 1 template and multiple json files. I don't want to explicitly name all the jsons one by one. Instead I want to specify the path to all json files, path to the template and then dist path so that it generates the HTML files based on the json file names.

Here is my grunt task:

```
mustache_render: {
      json_data: {
        files: [
          {expand: true,
           src: 'content/*.json',
           template: 'templates/menu-content.mustache',
           dest: 'publish/'}
        ]
      }
    }
```

But it is not creating the HTML files. Instead it creates multiple .json files with HTML code in it. Also note it creates the files in publish/content/ folder rather than publish/ where I intend them to be. Here is how the output looks like:

```
Output publish/content/page-one.json:
>> 2-key object into templates/menu-content.mustache from content/page-one.json
Output publish/content/page-three.json:
>> 5-key object into templates/menu-content.mustache from content/page-three.json
Output publish/content/page-two.json:
>> 5-key object into templates/menu-content.mustache from content/page-two.json
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to do what I am trying with grunt-mustache-render?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by dynamically generating your configuration for the `mustache_render` Task based on the `.json` files.

Try configuring your `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  grunt.initConfig({
    mustache_render: {} // Intentionally empty, will be auto generated.
  });

  /**
   * Helper function auto generates the configuration object for 
   * the mustache_render Task based on the .json files found.
   */
  function generateHtml() {
    var config = {},
      pathsToJson = 'content/*.json';

    grunt.file.expand(pathsToJson).forEach(function (filePath, index) {
      // .html filename based on .json filename.
      var htmlFileName = filePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0] + '.html';

      config[index] = {
        files : [{
          data: filePath,
          template: 'templates/menu-content.mustache',
          dest: 'publish/' + htmlFileName
        }]
      }
    });

    // Add the generated config object to mustache_render Task then run it.
    grunt.config('mustache_render', config);
    grunt.task.run(['mustache_render']);
  }

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mustache-render');
  grunt.registerTask('buildHtml', generateHtml);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['buildHtml']);
};
```